# How to receive messages in ascending by received date order in graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to receive email messages via Microsoft Graph API:

```
requestBuilder
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .Expand("attachments")
    .GetAsync(ChildCancellationToken.Token);
```

but messages come in descending order by ReceivedDateTime. For example we have 15 new messages with ReceivedDateTime = n, where n represents date time.
In first part will come:

```
[15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6 (deltaHash="someValue")]
```

in second:

```
[5,4,3,2,1 (deltaHash=NULL)]
```

So, the oldest email will come the latest (LIFO, not FIFO).
But I expect to get:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (deltaHash="someValue")]
[11,23,13,14,15 (deltaHash=NULL)]
```

What I tried: I tried OrderBy(string value).
For these two I get exceptions:

```
.OrderBy("ReceivedDateTime asc")
.OrderBy("ReceivedDateTime")
```

This is working fine:

```
.OrderBy("ReceivedDateTime desc")
```

but this is the same as default behavior and I think this is a bug actually. So there is no way to sort emails in ASC order.

How to solve on first look very simple and common requirement?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known issue as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages#use-query-parameters-in-a-delta-query-for-messages).

> The only supported $orderby expression is
> $orderby=receivedDateTime+desc. If you do not include an $orderby
> expression, the return order is not guaranteed.

So for now you need to sort them on your end by writing your own code.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did that exact the same way (sorting on client). But the company like Microsoft could provide more reliable API.

Comment: Yeah! May be in the future they may fix it. For now go ahead and reverse the descending order that you get by writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that .OrderBy("ReceivedDateTime asc") is now working as of the version of the microsoft-graph API I am using which is 5.36.0